# VBA, copying columns from multiple workbooks to master sheet,

Tags: vba, excel

Having trouble running this code. i am not able to copy multiple columns from multiple workbooks and compile them into my worksheet. The columns will be of same name or same order in each file i am looping though. When I run this code I am not getting any result or error.

```
       Option Explicit
Dim wsMaster As Workbook, csvFiles As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim File As Integer
Dim r As Long

Public Sub Consolidate()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select files to process"
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook

        For File = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

            Filename = .SelectedItems.Item(File)

           If Right(Filename, 4) = ".csv" Then
    Set csvFiles = Workbooks.Open(Filename, 0, True)
    r = wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    csvFiles.Sheets(1).Columns("col name").Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Offset(1, 0)
    csvFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close without saving
            End If


        Next File 'go to the next file and repeat the process

    End With

    Set wsMaster = Nothing
    Set csvFiles = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to open? It won't open a `.csv` file. It'll only open `.csvXX` where XX is more of the extension.  Perhaps you mean `If Right(Filename, 5) = ".csv" Then`?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, seems to just not do anything after i go through the file picker.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in the debugger to see where it's not executing as you expected? `F8` is your friend - put your cursor in your `Sub`, press `F8` slowly & repeatedly, and watch the magic (fail to) happen. Also, what @BruceWayne [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244886/vba-copying-columns-from-multiple-workbooks-to-master-sheet#comment77455864_45244886) - a `.CSV` file doesn't have an extra character in the extension, and if it does, `Right() = ".csv*"` won't match is - the `*` is _not_ a wild-card in VBA

Comment: What kind of file(s) are you trying to open?

Comment: @FreeMan `*` is a wildcard, but for Find methods. Same with `?`.

Comment: @Jonnyboi sorry, I had a typo earlier. Try `...Right(Filename,4)=".csv"`

Comment: @EganWolf yes, `*` will work as a wild card in the `.Find()` method, however the OP is checking for simple equality, and he won't find a file name ending with a literal `*` character.

Comment: @BruceWayne, made the change. Now getting an error on line `csvFiles.Sheets(1).Columns("col name").Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Offset(1, 0)` mismatch type.

Comment: `"col name"` is a string, but you need a number there...How do you know what column that is? Is that a named range? Did you forget to set a variable, and use `col name` instead of `"col name"`?

Comment: @FreeMan you are right, I just wanted to clarify that "the `*` is _not_ a wild-card in VBA" is a little misleading.

Comment: @BruceWayne , just thought I could specify the header name and it would copy that, but i guess ill need to use a # here?  edit, # doesnt seem to work, so i guess i have to set a variable? I wanted to search for a specific col name, or use col #.

Comment: @Jonnyboi if you use a number try `...Sheets(1).columns(1).EntireColumn.Copy`..or `...Sheets(1).Range("A:A").EntireColumn.copy` to use the letter

Comment: @BruceWayne,  now i get an information error that cannot be pased because copy and paste area are not the same size and shape. on this new line `csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: @Jonnyboi  are you trying to copy the whole column? Or a smaller range than a whole column? If a column, change the destination to be `.Range("A:A").Offset...`

Comment: @BruceWayne , whole column. which part does the offset go?

Comment: `csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Offset(0,1)` to offset the destination range by one column

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks batman. I have a question, this looks like it takes the last file of the pickers column and puts it to my workbook.. How can i combine them all?